# OpenGL Shaders. Pass array of float

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, uniform

On my scene i have many objects that i want to rotate at the same time but on different angles.

I have a shader that computes position of each object and draw the whole scene (pass vertex array into the shader with array of vertexes).

```
    "uniform float uRotation;" +
    ...
    "   mat4 mz = mat4(1.0);" +
    "   mz[0][0] = cos(rotation);" +
    "   mz[0][1] = sin(rotation);" +
    "   mz[1][0] = -sin(rotation);" +
    "   mz[1][1] = cos(rotation);" +
    ...
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * (aPosition *mz);
```

i have all my vertexes, indexes, colors etc in arrays (not 1 array for each object, but 1 array with offset for vertexes, one for colors etc.).

I want to pass array of floats (angles for each "object") in one float[], but nothing is happinig.

```
    public void setRotations(float[] rotations)
    {
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(muRotation, rotations.length, rotations, 0);    
    }
```

if pass and use only one float everything is ok.

How can i pass specific float for each object (for example i want to draw 20 rectangles (i have a vetrex array: float[20*3*4]) as i understand i must have float for each vertex: rotations: float[20*4])?

**UPDATED:**

I try to pass array as a texture.

When i create resources for the scene - i try to create my array (called mask):

```
    mask = new float[512*512*4];
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++)
    {
        mask[i] = 2f;
    }

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1029384756);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mask));
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Then when i draw new item on scene i use shader and try to pass my array:

```
    setShaderProgram(ShaderProgram.getInstance());

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.sUniformMask, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1029384756);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
```

But when i try to check any value from the array if it >0.5 every computation gives me **false**

**UPDATED**

Fragment shader contains:

```
"uniform sampler2D " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_0 + ";\n" +
"uniform sampler2D " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_1 + ";\n" +
"varying mediump vec2 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +

"void main() {\n" +
"vec4 color = texture2D(" + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_0 + ", " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ");\n" +
"vec4 mask = texture2D(" + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_1 + ", " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ");\n" +
"float maskVal = mask.r;\n" ...
```

color and mask textures have the same dimensions

Comment: You can pass your array as a one dimensional texture.You can also pass a block of uniforms as UBO but it won't help you much if your array is big.The best way is to fill a texture and send it over.

Comment: I've already have textures for each element, i can't understand what do you mean. Maybe you have some links for good tutorials ? Thx.

Comment: In fact you should check if ES supports one dimensional textures.You your array values into glTexImage1D​ and  use target of type GL_TEXTURE_1D.Then you can read it in the shader.I write it based on OpenGL desktop API.Check if you can do it in ES.

Comment: What are you doing in your shader. Do you have a Sampler2D and a texture coordinate to sample the texture?

Comment: Shader is very simple (check edits)

Comment: I played a bit with your code. This one change worked for me: GLES31.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES31.GL_R32F, 512, 512, 0, GLES31.GL_RED, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mask));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.sUniformMask, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);`

If this is your sampler uniform, it should read:

`GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.sUniformMask, 1);` (not GL_TEXTURE1)

Similar for sampler0:

`GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.sUniformMask, 0);`

Comment: maybe smth like glGentexture is needed ?

Comment: There is an error 1282 (invalid operation) when i try to GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderProgram.sUniformMask, 1);

Comment: @dilix Were you able to solve the error? Make sure your sUniformMask has a valid value, and that a valid shader is bound. There are several reasons why you can get an invalid operation, check the reasons at the bottom of [this page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml)

Comment: Yes, the trouble was i try to bid my unifore BEFORE i bin the fragment shader , thx =)