# Andengine set alpha for each pixel in sprite

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, fragment-shader

I have a one big Sprite on the Scene - for example 200x200 and in the app i have an array[200][200] in which i store 0 or 1 for each pixel in big sprite.

I want to draw one more textured sprite (for example 10x10) above existing one, but i want to calculate for eache pixel in new sprite if it needs to draw it on this scene depends on provided array (if in corresponding position of the pixel in new sprite in array is '1' - i need to draw this pixel, if '0' - i don't want to draw it (maybe set alpha = 0)).

I think i can use fragment shader for each of new sprites, but i can't understand how to provide array data to the shader to calculate color for each pixel.
I think also can use fragment shader for the whole scene (if render to texture).

I am quite new in opengl and can't figure out in what way to move.

When i create resources for the scene - i try to create my mask:

```
    mask = new float[512*512*4];
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++)
    {
        mask[i] = 2f;
    }

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1029384756);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mask));
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Then when i draw new item on scene i use shader:

```
    setShaderProgram(ShaderProgram.getInstance());

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(RadialBlurExample.RadialBlurShaderProgram.sUniformMask, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1029384756);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
```

But i can't see new item on scene (maskVal is <0.5).

I try to find working way to pass array as a texture but i can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload your array as a second texture with the same dimensions as the sprite, and then when you draw the sprite, sample the second texture at the same texcoord.

If the second texture doesn't meet the mask criteria, discard the fragment

```
uniform sampler2d sprite;
uniform sampler2d mask;
in vec2 uv;
main() {

   float maskVal = texture2D(mask, uv).r;
   if(maskVal > 0.5) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(sprite,uv);
   } else {
        discard;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it's a good idea, but how i know - "if" is very heavy operation for opengl, i think smth like "step" is suitable in this case. I'll try it and mark as answer if everything is ok for me.

Comment: @dilix Well if you don't want to draw the pixel, then you must use the `discard` statement, which you'll have to put inside an if block.

Comment: Can't i draw it but make it transparent ?

Comment: @dilix If you're talking about using blending, then you can draw a 0.0 alpha pixel to the screen, which will then be discarded by the blending operation, but it is much more efficient to discard it from the fragment shader. If you output the RGBA value from the frag shader without discarding it, it will either be drawn to the framebuffer if you have no blending, or it will be blended with the destination, which is a lot more work for the gpu than just discarding.

Comment: Tim, you can check one other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503271/opengl-shaders-pass-array-of-float

Comment: @dilix Same as I posted in your other question, texture sampler uniform should be `1`, not `GL_TEXTURE1`.